# Maximum Principle for Parabolic Equation on a Torus (reference request)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

In the book **Regularity Theory for Mean-Field Game Systems** Section 4.6 states the solution to the equation
$$ \partial_t v + \tilde{b} Dv = \Delta v + \psi \qquad \text{on } \mathbb{T}^d \times(0,T),$$
with terminal condition $v(x,T) = 0$ and $\tilde{b} : \mathbb{T}^d \times(0,T) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ smooth, is bounded provided $\psi$ is bounded ($\|v\|_\infty \leq C\|\psi\|_\infty)$. They briefly state this result follows from maximum principle; however, the maximum principles I find always requires some Dirichlet or Robin information of $v$ on the boundary of the domain. Is anyone aware of a reference for a parabolic maximum principle on the torus or on a square with periodic boundary conditions?